# Get a blank address

Tags: remix, addresses, mapping, struct, solidity-0.5.x

I have a little problem with my code. I'm trying to follow who are the current sender and the previous sender of a transaction respectively with the variable `currentSender` and `lastSender`, and then enregister them in a mapping nested in the struct `Order`. However trought the get function I created, I saw that all `lastSender` variable give me blank address, while `currentSender` give me the good address.

Here is code:

```
pragma solidity  ^0.5.16;

contract SupChain{
struct Status{
    address currentSender;
    address lastSender;
    string test;
    }

struct Order{
    uint256 orderID;
    uint256 NumberOfUpdate;
    string test2;
    mapping (uint256 => Status) statutes;
    }

uint256 public orderCount = 0;

mapping (uint256 => Order) public orders;


function createOrder(string memory test, string memory test2) public{
    orderCount++;
    Order storage newOrder = orders[orderCount];
    orders[orderCount] = Order(orderCount, 0, test2);
    newOrder.statutes[newOrder.NumberOfUpdate++] = Status(msg.sender, msg.sender, test);
    }

function storeOrder(uint256 id, string memory test) public{
    Order storage concernedOrder = orders[id];
    
    //Getting the previous sender before updating the NumberOfUpdate
    Status memory previousStatus = concernedOrder.statutes[concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate];
    address previousSender = previousStatus.currentSender;
    
    concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate = concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate++;
    concernedOrder.statutes[concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate++] = 
                            Status(msg.sender, previousSender, test);
    }

function getStatus(uint256 id, uint256 concernedStatusNumber) public view              
                   returns(address _currentSender, address _lastSender, 
                           string memory _test){
    Order storage concernedOrder = orders[id];
    Status memory concernedStatus = concernedOrder.statutes[concernedStatusNumber];
    return(concernedStatus.currentSender, concernedStatus.lastSender, 
           concernedStatus.test);

    }
}
```

So, I would like to request some help to resolve this problem please.

I thank in advance anybody who will take the time to help me.

What I tried:

Omitting the incrementation of new order from the `createOrder` function and obviusly leaving else the same as before:

```
function storeOrder(uint256 id, string memory test) public{
    Order storage concernedOrder = orders[id];

    //Getting the previous sender before updating the NumberOfUpdate
    Status memory previousStatus = concernedOrder.statutes[concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate];
    address previousSender = previousStatus.currentSender;

    concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate = concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate++;
    concernedOrder.statutes[concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate] = 
                            Status(msg.sender, previousSender, test);
    }
```

Adding a decrementation to the variable `previousStatus` of the `storeOrder` function and leaving else the same as before:

```
function storeOrder(uint256 id, string memory test) public{
    Order storage concernedOrder = orders[id];

    //Getting the previous sender before updating the NumberOfUpdate
    Status memory previousStatus = concernedOrder.statutes[concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate--];
    address previousSender = previousStatus.currentSender;

    concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate = concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate++;
    concernedOrder.statutes[concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate++] = 
                            Status(msg.sender, previousSender, test);
    }
```

Now I'm seing if the problem doesn't come from my `getStatus` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the error... it was a really vicious one.

Basically when I was writting:

```
concernedOrder.statutes[concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate++] = Status(msg.sender, previousSender, test);
```

The incrementation didn't increment the `Status` position inside of `statutes` but the number of updates of `Order` ! So to have the good position I need to use `+1` in place of `++`.
Here is the good code:

```
pragma solidity  ^0.5.16;

contract SupChain{
struct Status{
    address currentSender;
    address lastSender;
    string test;
}

struct Order{
    uint256 orderID;
    uint256 NumberOfUpdate;
    string test2;
    mapping (uint256 => Status) statutes;
}

uint256 public orderCount = 0;

mapping (uint256 => Order) public orders;

function createOrder(string memory test, string memory test2) public{
    orders[orderCount] = Order(orderCount, 0, test2); 
    orders[orderCount].statutes[orders[orderCount].NumberOfUpdate] = Status(msg.sender, msg.sender, test);
    orderCount++;
}

function storeOrder(uint256 id, string memory test) public{
    orders[id].statutes[orders[id].NumberOfUpdate + 1] = Status(msg.sender, orders[id].statutes[orders[id].NumberOfUpdate].currentSender, test);
    orders[id].NumberOfUpdate++;
}

function getStatus(uint256 id, uint256 concernedStatusNumber) public view returns(address _currentSender, address _lastSender, string memory _test){
    Order storage concernedOrder = orders[id];
    Status memory concernedStatus = concernedOrder.statutes[concernedStatusNumber];
    return(concernedStatus.currentSender, concernedStatus.lastSender, concernedStatus.test);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting empty `lastSender` is because you are incrementing `newOrder.NumberOfUpdate++` when you create order. It stores the status at index `0` and increments the variable. When you set the order, it retrieves the incremented value, which is `1` at that point and it does not have a status against this index because the status was stored at index `0`.

You can either omit the incrementing in `createOrder` or you can decrement the  `NumberOfUpdate` by `1` when retrieving old status in `setOrder`.

Comment: Just tried both method but they didn't work. I omitted the incrementing in `newOrder.statutes[newOrder.NumberOfUpdate++]`  from the function `createOrder` without touching anything else but didn't work. The same when I decremented `concernedOrder.statutes[concernedOrder.NumberOfUpdate]` from the `storeOrder` function...

Answer (score 0):

Your createOrder is confusing, try like that

```
function createOrder(string memory test, string memory test2) public{
    orderCount++;
    orders[orderCount] = Order(orderCount, 0, test2);
    orders[orderCount].NumberOfUpdate++;
    orders[orderCount].statutes[orders[orderCount].NumberOfUpdate] = Status(msg.sender, msg.sender, test);
}
```

I would recommend to not start your order count at 1, it's confusing to deal with array / mapping without 0 index as developer. Something like that looks better from my point of view.

```
function createOrder(string memory test, string memory test2) public{
    // orderCount  is 0 for first order
    orders[orderCount] = Order(orderCount, 0, test2); 

    // first update update is stored at 0
    orders[orderCount].statutes[orders[orderCount].NumberOfUpdate] = Status(msg.sender, msg.sender, test);

    orders[orderCount].NumberOfUpdate++;
    orderCount++;
}
```